# What does the ~1 mean in this git reset command?

Tags: git

> git reset HEAD~1

I was under the impression that the ~1 meant: start at the HEAD, follow 1 link, and set the HEAD tag to that new commit node. I was expecting

> git reset HEAD~2

to follow 2 links and then set the HEAD tag. However, if I try it, I get an error:

```
$ git reflog
c83bbda HEAD@{0}: reset: moving to HEAD~1
44c3540 HEAD@{1}: commit: you will be garbage soon
c83bbda HEAD@{2}: reset: moving to HEAD~1
aee7955 HEAD@{3}: commit: back to 4 lines
c83bbda HEAD@{4}: reset: moving to HEAD~1
19ec1d5 HEAD@{5}: commit: 3 lines
c83bbda HEAD@{6}: reset: moving to HEAD~1
a049538 HEAD@{7}: commit: added new line
c83bbda HEAD@{8}: commit (initial): first commit


$ git reset --hard HEAD~2
fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD~2': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

Apparently I was mistaken, but the doc page for git reset is not very useful in clarifying this. So, what does the ~1 mean and why do I need it?

Comment: In this particular case, the "unknown revision" part means that `HEAD~2` simply does not exist.  `HEAD` is commit `c83bbda` according to the reflog, and that's your initial commit, so it has no parents, and `HEAD^`, `HEAD~1`, etc., simply don't exist.

Comment: Please study the [`gitrevisions(7)` manual](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) which explains all these `~` and `^` funny characters.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the difference between ~ and ^ in git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14733687/whats-the-difference-between-and-in-git)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Git Revision Expression?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215814/what-is-a-git-revision-expression)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`HEAD~1` is "the first parent of `HEAD`", while `HEAD~2` is "the first parent of the first parent of `HEAD`, and so on (so `HEAD~n` for some n is like `HEAD` followed by n `^` symbols and no numbers).  Again, all the specifics are in the [git-rev-parse](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-parse.html) manual page.

Be careful when mixing `git reset` with "revisions counting backwards from `HEAD`".  `git reset` will, in general, *change* the value of `HEAD`, e.g.:

```
$ git checkout master    # now on tip of "master" branch
$ git branch save master # copy branch tip to another label, for safekeeping
$ git reset HEAD^        # or git reset HEAD~1
```

moves `HEAD` (and `master`) to its first parent.  Another way to name that parent is `save^`, and yet another is `save~1`.  After the move finishes, though, `HEAD` now names that parent revision, so `HEAD^` names *its* parent:

```
$ git reset HEAD^
```

moves you back another step, so that `master` and `HEAD` now name the same commit that `save~2` names.  This is easy to see using `git rev-parse`, which tells you the commit-ID that some symbolic-name maps to:

```
$ git rev-parse save~2 master
0f5a13497dd3da8aff8e452c8f56630f83253e79
0f5a13497dd3da8aff8e452c8f56630f83253e79
```

At this point, you can restore `master` to the save-point with:

```
$ git reset save
```

which moves `HEAD` and `master` back to the saved revision, and then you can delete `save` safely if you like:

```
$ git branch -d save
```

Note that you could save a save-point with `git tag` too: the only difference between a branch and a tag is the behavior of new check-ins when "on a branch" (tags don't move, branches do) and check-outs (tags put you in "detached HEAD" = not-on-a-branch state, branch names put you in "on-a-branch" state).

Answer (score 3):

See [`git help revisions`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) or [Git - Revision Selection](http://git-scm.com/book/ch6-1.html) for more details on how to specify a commit:

> ```
> <rev>~<n>, e.g. master~3
> ```
>
> A suffix `~<n>` to a revision parameter means the commit object that is the `<n>th`
>           generation ancestor of the named commit object, following only the first parents. I.e. `<rev>~3` is equivalent to `<rev>^^^` which is equivalent to `<rev>^1^1^1`.

This syntax can be used with most Git commands, so it's not specific to `git reset`.

Answer (score 2):

`git reser --hard HEAD~1` removes the last 1 (or any other number you put) commit from the current branch, like this
`git reset HEAD`  ... removes the last commit
`git reset HEAD~1` ... remove the last 2 commits
and so on

Comment: Almost: `git reset HEAD` won't remove a commit.  The default for `reset` is `reset --mixed` which resets the index but does not change the working tree, and in any case, `HEAD` names "where you are now" so this does not move a branch label either.  Thus, what it achieves is to undo the effect of any `git add`s and/or `git rm --cached`.  (It's also an overstatement to say that it *removes* commits, it just makes the commits *appear* to vanish, by changing the SHA-1 values for branch names.  They eventually go away via `git gc`.)

Answer (score 1):

You get this error message when you run `git reset --hard HEAD~2`

```
fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD~2': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
```

because you're trying to reset your working copy to a commit that doesn't exist. According to your reflog, you have your initial root commit checked out when running this command:

```bash
$ git reflog
c83bbda HEAD@{0}: reset: moving to HEAD~1
# etc ...
c83bbda HEAD@{8}: commit (initial): first commit
```

So according to the reflog above, you're current working copy, i.e. `HEAD`, is at your first commit, so by doing `git reset --hard head~2` from here, you're telling Git to go back 2 commits ***before your first commit***, which of course it can't do because nothing exists before your first commit:

```
fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD~2': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
```